# Mongo result as JSON

Tags: php, mongodb, rest

Using following code to convert as document to JSON is:

```
print( json_encode((new MongoClient())->db->col->findOne()));
//Output:{"_id":{"$id":"52838520f7c255c009000000"},"test":"test"}
```

Is there any way to set Mongo to return _id field as string instead of object? Is it safe to return _id value to client side script (as the response of a GET request)

I do not want manually convert _id to string and vice versa when implementing a REST api.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is nothing you can do (mongod in comparison to SQL can not do modification of the fields it is outputting). Therefore you only resort is to do what you *didn't want* to do (manually convert). But it is not hard, all you need to do is one of these:

- `(string)$doc['_id'];`
- `(string)$doc->_id;`
- `$doc['_id']->{'$id'};`